# dependency conflict when build react-native-firebase for Android (Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzb$1)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build react-native firebase for android, and keep getting error on build 
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/docs/installation.android.md

here is the error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzb$1;
```

I check `gradle app:dependencies` and see that `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base` is being add as version `10.2.1` and `10.2.0`. `react-native-push-notification` add version `10.2.1` for `play-services`. I think this might be the reason, here is the output for dependencies

```
+--- project :react-native-firebase
|    +--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.42.0 (*)
|    +--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.10
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.2.0
|    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.0
|    |              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |              |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|    |              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:10.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:10.2.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
+--- project :bugsnag-react-native
|    +--- com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:3.7.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1 -> 25.0.0
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.42.0 (*)
+--- project :react-native-push-notification
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.42.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+ -> 10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:10.2.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    \--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.8 -> 1.1.10
+--- project :react-native-vector-icons
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.42.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 25.0.0 (*)
\--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.42.0 (*)
```

my top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

My `app` build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile project(':bugsnag-react-native')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Below are the dependencies that worked for me**

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
compile project(':react-native-firebase')
compile project(':bugsnag-react-native')
compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are adding it in twice via "firebase-core" and ":react-native-firebase":

```
dependencies {
    // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0' <- try removing this, "firebase-core" is already in ":react-native-firebase"
    // compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])  <- try not to add jars
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile project(':bugsnag-react-native')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: close :D, I post my full dependencies that solve my problem

Comment: @ThangPham Did this work for you? Can you mark as correct?

Comment: Not quite, I posted my solutions above.

Answer (score 1):

What helped building the APK for me was enabling multiDex:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

=> for minSDK >=21:

```
`android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}`
```

=> for minSDK <21:

```
`android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}`
```